# ERROR: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am getting no suitable driver exception. Connection is not created.

```
package org.srtmun.student.dao.impl;
import javax.transaction.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.srtmun.student.dao.RegestrationDAO;
import org.srtmun.student.hibernateplugin.HibernatePlug;
import org.srtmun.student.model.Registration;

public class RegistrationDaoImpl implements RegestrationDAO{
    public void addStudent(Registration register) {
        System.out.println("RegistrationDaoImpl class1");
        SessionFactory factory = HibernatePlug.getFactory();
        System.out.println("1");
        Session session=factory.openSession();
        org.hibernate.Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(register);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
    }
}  


<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">123</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <mapping resource="Registration.hbm.xml" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is my code and and iam facing the Same issue.

Comment: where is your driver? <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this property to the `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<property 
  name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
```

And you need to have [mysql-connector-java jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java) at the class path.

Your transaction code is not correct (you don't use rollback, for an example). Refer [this](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-core/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/factory/HibernateSessionFactory.java#L41) for how to properly work with that.